# Using .htaccess to redirect all sub-folder's directory to Root (main) Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Let say my domain is `http://example.com/`, and I have a page such as `http://example.com/abc/`(Used rewrite rule to remove the extension of the page file).

But sometimes, user type `http://example.com/abc/xxx/` (xxx is a various, so many chance they type) such as `http://example.com/abc/1njnsdc`, `http://example.com/abc/diief123/`, etc. Normally, it will make request to server to need `/abc/xxx/`, `/abc/injnsdc/`, `/abc/diief123/` etc. Unluckily, we don't have files inside the folder `/abc/` so the server should be return 404 error, not found.

I hope to make a rewrite rule to make server get request like `http://example.com/abc/xxx/`, `http://example.com/abc/1njnsdc/`, `http://example.com/abc/diief123/` will not return 404 but respond redirect to `http://example.com/abc/`. Another static request from me is the URL cannot change. So that once the user type `http://example.com/abc/xxx/`, `http://example.com/abc/1njnsdc/`, `http://example.com/abc/diief123/` etc, all of that will can access to what user type `http://example.com/abc/???/`. And user is still reading the page `http://example.com/abc/`.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to redirect the 404 page to the main page!
if you don't want it to show at all.
if you are using php this could be useful for you:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: no, this is not a dynamic page, so that it should be use .htaccess to modifty

Comment: you may use this with some edition : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: /abc/ is html page, so any solution are suitable for html?